# Style.display="inline" show the table row in unwanted way, is there any way to fix it?

Tags: html, css, inline, css-tables

I'm using radio button and when the user clicks on it a row in the table will be shown, I used *style="display:none;"* to hide it and the code below in Javascript to show it:

```
document.getElementById("testId").style.display = "inline";
```

the problem is the way it is displayed, since I just signed up I can't upload the picture of how it is displayed but I will try to show it as much as I can.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
this is before 
----------------------------------------------------------------
this is test test test test | this is the row
----------------------------------------------------------------

******************

--------------------------------------------------
this is after showing it with inline
--------------------------------------------------
this | this is the row
 is  |
test |
test |
test |
test |
```

Also I noticed this way of displaying this row happens only in the browsers other than IE!
Is there any way of fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used style="display:none;" to hide it and the code below in java script to show it
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("testId").style.display = "inline";
> ```

`inline` is not the correct initial display value for table rows – it’s `table-row`, of course.

But since older IE don’t understand this correctly, you should just set it to an empty string,

```
document.getElementById("testId").style.display = "";
```

– this will make the browser simply reset the display style to what the browser thinks is the correct default display value for a table row.